# Computer reboots itself after login - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, login, lightdm, reboot

I have a really weird problem:
I have an Ubuntu 16.04.5 Desktop with two users, one regular and one with sudo privileges.

After I turn on the PC, it boots to the LightDM Login. If I log in to the Sudo user - all is well, but when I try to log in to the regular user (UID 1001) - the computer reboots right before showing the Desktop...

I verified the user is not locked (`passwd -u`) and I also tried deleting the `~/.Xauthority` file - all it did is show me the Desktop for a split second and **then** it reboots...

This is a really annoying problem because I need to start working on a project in a week with this user's files.

Comment: I would have checked the permissions of the .Xauthority file first. If no more specific solution is found, create a new user account and move that user's own file there.

Comment: Can a permission problem cause a reboot of the whole machine?

Comment: Who knows. Do I understand it right that, after entering the users pasword, the computer reboots, then immediately takes you to the user's desktop without again asking for a paswoord? Are you sure it is really a reboot you experience?

Comment: No. What happens after I enter the user's password, the computer reboots, as if I entered the command reboot at the terminal. The same does not happen when I log in to the sudo user.

Comment: OK, I see. It is the "right before showing the desktop" that could be misunderstood: this sounds as if the desktop is shown afterwards. Some malicious autostart program doing a reboot? User autostart items are in .config/autostart